# Cannot connect to Team Fortress 2 item server?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

It says "loadout not available - no connection to Steam"...what? What does this mean? I'm pretty sure I'm connected to Steam.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me every once in awhile.  Sometimes it fixes itself if you don't play for a bit (and by that I mean an hour up to a day) but if it doesn't fix itself, try restarting steam or your computer.